# Android Serialization of static field in object

Tags: java, android, serialization, static

In Android i'm currently serializing an object which contains a non-serializable field (An Outputstream) in one activity and retrieving it in another activity. When doing this i obviously get an error, saying the Outputstream is not serializable, but when setting the Outputstream to static in the object it success. I'm guessing it just ignores the Outputstream when serializing? But nevertheless i'm able to retrieve the same Outputstream from activity 1 in activity 2 from the object after serializing.

My question is, how am i able to retrieve this Outputstream from the object after serilization, since it shouldn't be able to serialize the Outputstream?

Here is the object i'm serializing:

```
public class ObjectContainingOutputStream implements Serializable{

 private static OutputStream mmOutStream;

   public static OutputStream getMmOutStream() {
      return mmOutStream;
   }

   public void setMmOutStream(OutputStream mmOutStream) {
      this.mmOutStream = mmOutStream;
   }
}
```

Here is how i serialize the object:

bluetooth.getConnection.getMmOutStream() returns an Outputstream.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, ChangeDataActivity.class);
ObjectContainingOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectContainingOutputStream();   
outputStream.setMmOutStream(bluetooth.getConnection().getMmOutStream());
bundle.putSerializable("OutPutStream", outputStream);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Here is how i retrieve the serialized object:

```
ObjectContainigOutputStream container = ((ObjectContainingOutputStream) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("OutPutStream"));
Outputstream outputstream = container.getMmOutStream();
```

Comment: I don't think Android Studio is part of your problem.

Comment: I don't actually have a problem since i do recieve the Outputstream which i needed, i'm just not sure how and at the same time afraid i'm doing something "illegal".

Comment: Why not just get the data out of the stream before serializing the containing object?

Comment: I don't see that you even are serializing the object. I suggest replacing the android-studio tag with android, to find someone to more fully answer your question.